# use algorithm function max_element with function parametrer

Tags: algorithm, functor

I have a probleme by using max_element with 3 parametres :
My list

```
list<T*> myList_;
```

the function

```
template<typename T>
T TheObject<T>::bigger () const{
    return *(*(max_element(myList_.begin(), myList_.end(), compare)));
}

template<typename T>
bool TheObject<T>::compare(const T* a, const T* b)
{
    return *a < *b;
}
```

Why I have this error

> Error 1 : 'TheObject::compare': function call missing argument
> list; use '&TheObject::compare' to create a pointer to member  obj.h
>
> Error 2 : '_FwdIt std::max_element(_FwdIt,_FwdIt)' : expects 2
> arguments - 3 provided obj.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you provide to `std::max_element` (and other standard algorithms) cannot be a non-static member function, since it will not be called as a member function. (`std::max_element` has no idea what `this` might be.)

The first error message you're getting is accurate, but possibly misleading. Because `compare` is not a free-standing function, but rather a non-static member function, you cannot use it as a function pointer, only as a pointer-to-member-function. And the syntax of a pointer-to-member-function is &Class::member. Fixing that won't help, though, because `std::max_element` cannot make use of a pointer-to-member-function as its third argument.